# Is F# in visual studio 11 Developer Preview?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2012

Whether there is in Visual Studio 11 F#.

> Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview is an integrated development environment that seamlessly spans the entire life cycle of software creation, including architecture, user interface design, code creation, code insight and analysis, code deployment, testing, and validation. This release adds support for the most advanced Microsoft platforms, including the next version of Windows (code-named "Windows 8") and Windows Azure, and enables you to target platforms across devices, services, and the cloud. Integration with Team Foundation Server allows the entire team, from the customer to the developer, to build scalable and high-quality applications to exacting standards and requirements.

Comment: You could try it and find out. You could also ask yourself if C# is in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview.

Comment: This is a very easy thing to find out if you just tried it. I'm curious as to why you would ask without looking yourself. Perhaps you only looked at the Windows 8 dev preview, which does not contain F#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

[image: VS 11 F#]

Comment: J# is discontinued. Besides, you can see all the languages that are supported out of the box in the screenshot.